# Html <ul> list changing certain list text color and background color

Tags: css, html-lists

My html:

```
<ul class="tech">
  <li>JavaScript</li>
  <li>HTML / CSS</li>
  <li>PHP + MYSQL</li>
  <li>C#</li>
  <li class="software">PhotoShop</li>
  <li class="software">Brackets</li>
  <li class="software">Notepad++</li>
  <li class="software">Sony Vegas</li>
  <li class="software">eBay BlackThorne Pro</li>
  <li class="software">Senuke XCr</li>
  <li class="software2">X-Cart</li>
  <li class="software2">EKM PowerShop</li>
  <li class="software2">WordPress</li>
  <li class="software2">phpBB</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Css part of this html:

```
.tech ul {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    list-style:none;
    list-style-position:outside;
}
.tech li{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: #222222;
  margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;

  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 5px #000000;
  border: #969696 1px dashed;
}

.sofware {
    background-color:#646464;
    color: #ff7225;
}

.sofware2 {
    background-color:#4d4d4d;
    color: #fd205e; 
}
```

Problem: list items which software and sofware2 ids doesn't change color. What's the problem? Something should be like this I guess I should set those colors with "UL Li:nth-child" but I'm not sure how to do that.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. Try using classes instead.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.  You cannot have duplicate `id`s within a document.  Use `class`es instead to target multiple elements.

Comment: Does not fix the problem.

Comment: In your CSS .sofware should be .software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the jsfiddle says it works: http://jsfiddle.net/nLWAE/1/

```
<ul class="tech">
  <li>JavaScript</li>
  <li>HTML / CSS</li>
  <li>PHP + MYSQL</li>
  <li>C#</li>
  <li class="software">PhotoShop</li>
  <li class="software">Brackets</li>
  <li class="software">Notepad++</li>
  <li class="software">Sony Vegas</li>
  <li class="software">eBay BlackThorne Pro</li>
  <li class="software">Senuke XCr</li>
  <li class="software2">X-Cart</li>
  <li class="software2">EKM PowerShop</li>
  <li class="software2">WordPress</li>
  <li class="software2">phpBB</li>
</ul>

.tech ul {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    list-style:none;
    list-style-position:outside;
}
.tech li{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: #222222;
  margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;

  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 5px #000000;
  border: #969696 1px dashed;
}
.software {
    background-color:#646464;
    color: #ff7225;
}

.software2 {
    background-color:#4d4d4d;
    color: #fd205e; 
}
```

Comment: check again the second one.

Comment: Your first attempt was wrong because you cannot have duplicate `id`s.

Answer (score 2):

First, your CSS selectors don't match your `id`s.  You have "software" in the id, but "sofware" in the CSS selector.  But you also have duplicate `id`s, which is wrong.

Change your

```
<li id="software"></li>
<li id="software2"></li>
```

to

```
<li class="software"></li>
<li class="software2"></li>
```

then change your CSS to:

```
.tech li.software {
    background-color:#646464;
    color: #ff7225;
}

.tech li.software2 {
    background-color:#4d4d4d;
    color: #fd205e; 
}
```

Comment: i already tried that, jsfiddle worked but he said it didn't work.